# Convert xml text in a cell to Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

Our front end development team saves surveys in a SQL database table as xml text. Each survey has  different set of fields and need help on how to automatically convert the cell holding the xml text to multiple columns.

Below is an example of the xml text in a cell which needs to be split into individual columns.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<root>    
    <userid>JS 30/08/1981</userid>    
    <column___1>0</column___1>    
    <column___2>1</column___2>    
    <column___3>0</column___3>    
    <column___4>0</column___4>    
    <column___5>0</column___5>    
    <column___6>0</column___6>    
    <column___7>0</column___7>    
    <column___8>0</column___8>    
    <column___9>0</column___9>    
    <column___1_0>0</column___1_0>    
    <column___1_1>0</column___1_1>    
    <column___1_2>0</column___1_2>    
    <column___1_3>0</column___1_3>    
    <column___1_4>0</column___1_4>    
    <column___1_5>0</column___1_5>    
    <column___1_6>0</column___1_6>    
    <column___1_7>0</column___1_7>    
    <column___1_8>0</column___1_8>    
    <column___1_9>0</column___1_9>    
    <column___2_0>0</column___2_0>    
    <column___2_1>0</column___2_1>    
    <column___D_S>0</column___D_S>    
    <column___A_S>2</column___A_S>    
    <column___S_S>0</column___S_S>    
    <userid___u_i_d>5</userid___u_i_d>
</root>
```

Comment: Which database are you using

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to save this data into tables in the database or just convert them to html tables for display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test table using the syntax below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlTest](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [surveyxml] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I then loaded 2 records into the test table(the 1st being the XML you have in your example).

Use a query like below:

```
SELECT
      fields.value('(userid/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as userid,
      fields.value('(column___1/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as column1,
       fields.value('(column___2/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as column2,          
       fields.value('(column___3/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as column3
FROM  
      xmltest CROSS APPLY
      surveyxml.nodes('/root') AS Root(fields)
```

The following results are returned:

[image]

You can add all the fields you want to the query, and change the data type if you know what it is. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as generic dynamic code like this:

```
 drop table if exists #tmp

 DECLARE @XML as xml

 SET @XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
 <root>
     <userid>JS 30/08/1981</userid>    
     <column___1>0</column___1>    
     <column___2>1</column___2>    
     <column___3>0</column___3>    
     <column___4>0</column___4>    
     <column___5>0</column___5>    
     <column___6>0</column___6>    
     <column___7>0</column___7>    
     <column___8>0</column___8>    
     <column___9>0</column___9>    
     <column___1_0>0</column___1_0>    
     <column___1_1>0</column___1_1>    
     <column___1_2>0</column___1_2>    
     <column___1_3>0</column___1_3>    
     <column___1_4>0</column___1_4>    
     <column___1_5>0</column___1_5>    
     <column___1_6>0</column___1_6>    
     <column___1_7>0</column___1_7>    
     <column___1_8>0</column___1_8>    
     <column___1_9>0</column___1_9>    
     <column___2_0>0</column___2_0>    
     <column___2_1>0</column___2_1>    
     <column___D_S>0</column___D_S>    
     <column___A_S>2</column___A_S>    
     <column___S_S>0</column___S_S>    
     <userid___u_i_d>5</userid___u_i_d>
 </root>
 '

 /* First find all the column names and values */
 SELECT  
    b.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(50)') AS ColumnName,
     b.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ColumnValue
     into #tmp  
 FROM      @xml.nodes('/root') x(x)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('*') a(b)


 /* Now build the select */
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''
 select @sql=@sql+'
 '+iif(@sql='','',',')+''''+ ColumnValue + '''['+ColumnName+']'
 from #tmp

 set @sql='select '+@sql

 exec sp_executesql @sql
```